# Copy cells data into macro to avoid updating the macro

Tags: excel, vba, input, cell

I want to insert the content of a cell or a row of cells into a macro to avoid having to update the macro code.

This is so that people at my office can simply update a list in a spreadsheet instead of having to go change the VBA code.

Is it possible to simply ask Excel to insert text from a cell into VBA and use it to execute the macro?

Thank you!

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far... Your code can reference the list in the spreadsheet  - no need to have the specific text within your code.

Comment: Let say I want A B C written in my code. I have A and C in my code, but I know B will change over time, so I want B to be inserted from a cell so that I can only change the cell and not have to deal with my code.

Comment: Then just reference the `.Value` of the `Range` "B" is in. My point being if you have some code already, please share it, as well as what cell "B" is in, and we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive I understand your question, however to read data from a cell you would use

```
Worksheet(SheetIndex).Cells(x,y).Value
```

If you want to loop through rows to get the data doing a for loop would be the easiest way around it.

```
For i to j
    'Do Stuff
Next
```

If you want to loop through all rows in a sheet find the total number of rows by getting number of used cells.

```
Worksheet(SheetIndex).UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Honestly, I would probably have a button to actually trigger the start of this to increase usability. Code should always be written with scalability in mind so why would they need to change the macro code?

Comment: Let say I want A B C written in my code. I have A and C in my code, but I know B will change over time, so I want B to be inserted from a cell so that I can only change the cell and not have to deal with my code.

Comment: Ofcourse, that is where reading the cell value comes in. Just add the value in the cells and have the code call: `Worksheet(SheetIndex).Cells(x,y).Value`